# Action "Outbound SMS" from Contact screen not working

Tags: sms, civisms

Appears to be a new problem, wondering if it's working for other CiviSMS users. It works well when a contact is check-marked in search results and the action invoked from that screen. However if click on the contact and then select action "Outbound SMS" the "To" field is not pre-populated and non-functional.

[image]

[image]

CiviCRM 5.40.2, Twilio extension 1.2.1, Drupal 7.82

Comment: and the phone number of that contact is correctly formatted etc and is def. a mobile number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some problems in 5.40 with sms if using popup screens. It's fixed in 5.40.3 https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2777.

Temporary workaround if you don't want to update is turn off popups at administer - customize - display preferences.

Comment: The workaround addressed the problem so your diagnosis is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Confirming that upgrading to CiviCRM 5.40.4 corrected the problem, the workaround isn't needed any longer. Thanks again.